# Multiple 'exec' and 'print' commands in one file

Tags: ruby

Using a semicolon doesn't work when mixing `exec` commands and `print` commands.What is the best way to do this?

```
print "Initializing tests...\n"
print 'Testing 00_hello\n'
exec  'cd 00_hello; rspec hello_spec.rb; cd ..'
print 'Testing 01_temperature\n'
exec  'cd 01_temperature; rspec temperature_spec.rb; cd ..'
```

Answer (score 6):

You're mixing up `exec` with `system`. `exec` *replaces* the current process with running the command of the argument. If you want to run the file and wait for it and get control back, you need to use `system`:

```
print "Initializing tests...\n"
print 'Testing 00_hello\n'
system  'cd 00_hello; rspec hello_spec.rb; cd ..'
print 'Testing 01_temperature\n'
system  'cd 01_temperature; rspec temperature_spec.rb; cd ..'
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're asking why the last two lines of your file won't execute, that has nothing to do with your use of semicolons. `exec` replaces the current process. Any code following a call to `exec` will not execute because the process stops executing as soon as `exec` is called. In most cases you want to use `system`, not `exec`.

I should also point out that it's not necessary to do `cd ..` at the end of a command given to `exec` or `system`. `cd` only affects the shell it is executed in and any processes spawned from that shell -- it does not affect the parent process. So if you `cd` inside a shell command, your ruby process won't be affected by that, so there's no need to `cd` back.

Oh and you can't use escape sequences like `\n` inside single quoted strings, they will just appear as a backslash followed by the letter n. You need to use double quoted strings if you want to use `\n`. If you use `puts` instead of `print`, it'll automatically insert a linebreak at the end, so you won't need the `\n` at all.

Answer (score 0):

placing the string between backquote(`) will execute the string as system command.

for example try this.

```
print "Initializing tests...\n"
print 'Testing 00_hello\n'
`cd 00_hello; rspec hello_spec.rb; cd ..`
print 'Testing 01_temperature\n'
`cd 01_temperature; rspec temperature_spec.rb; cd ..`
```

Comment: Backticks return the output of the command as a string without printing it. That's fine if that's what you want, but in your code you're not doing anything with the returned strings, so the output is just discarded. And I'm pretty sure the OP wanted to see the output.

Comment: @Sachin is there a way to interpolate with backticks?

Comment: @dresdin: yes, use `#{}` like in strings.